# dumping the SparkConf object of a SparkContext

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'm using an ipython notebook to interact with a spark cluster.  The notebook set's up the `SparkContext` and stores it in a variable `sc`.

Is it possible to dump the values of the `SparkConf` so that I can see how the notebook is connecting to the spark cluster?

I've tried:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint (vars(sc._conf))
```

That gives me:

```
{'_jconf': JavaObject id=o0}
```

So I tried:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint (vars(sc._conf._jconf))
```

And that returns:

```
{'_auto_field': False,
 '_gateway_client': <py4j.java_gateway.GatewayClient object at 0xb201c30c>,
 '_methods': {'Java': <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0xb202c1cc>,
              'contains': <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0xb201cdac>,
              'get': <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0xb201ce4c>,
              'getAll': <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0xb201ce2c>,
              'set': <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0xb201c12c>,
              'setAppName': <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0xb201c76c>},
 '_target_id': u'o0'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `getAll` method:

```
sc._conf.getAll()

## [('spark.rdd.compress', 'True'),
##  ('spark.executor.memory', '8g'),
##  ('spark.serializer.objectStreamReset', '100'),
##      ...
## ('spark.app.name', 'PySparkShell')]
```